# How do I ensure logging of uncaught exceptions in a Django Huey task?

Tags: django, logging, python-huey

The standard Django logging setup doesn't catch logging of exceptions in a [Huey](http://huey.readthedocs.org) task.

This means that important tasks fail silently by default.

How can I make sure the exceptions are logged?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `huey` logger to your `settings.LOGGING`.  For example:

```
# settings.py

...

LOGGING = {
    ...
    'loggers': {
       ...
       'huey': {
         'handlers': ['error', 'mail_admins'],
         'level': 'ERROR',
         'propagate': False
       },
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? I tried this but didn't work. Did you find a solution by any chance @seddonym? I asked a kinda-related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60341868/1211429