# Huey Task Queue handle error on last retry only & retrieve exception traceback

Tags: python, django, python-huey

Currently have this snippet set up in my `tasks.py` so that an email is sent to the Django project's admins by `huey` whenever a task fails:

```
from django.core.mail import mail_admins

from huey import signals
from huey.contrib import djhuey as huey


@huey.signal(signals.SIGNAL_ERROR)
def task_error(signal, task, exc):
    subject = f'Task [{task.name}] failed
    message = f"""Task ID: {task.id}'
Args: {task.args}
Kwargs: {task.kwargs}
Exception: {exc}"""
    mail_admins(subject, message)
```

This results in the following (example) email subject

```
[Django] Task [test_task] failed
```

and body:

```
Task ID: 89e4bfb3-3cd3-4d6f-8693-68874caf21ec
Args: (123,)
Kwargs: {}
Exception: division by zero
```

which is pretty slick but... questions:

1. Right now, this is triggered whenever a task fails, including retries. I would like it to be sent only in the case all retries failed. So if a task has `retries=2`, right now I receive 3 emails (original error + 2 retries). How to have it send the email only on the last retry?
2. Is there a way to print the exception's `exc` traceback?

P.S. I tried setting it up via Django project logging, but this approach offers finer-grained control, so I'm satisfied with it.

### Update

The module with updates based on @Adam Chainz & @coleifer's answers (both correct), now looks like:

```
import traceback

from django.core.mail import mail_admins

from huey import signals
from huey.contrib import djhuey as huey


@huey.signal(signals.SIGNAL_ERROR)
def task_error(signal, task, exc):
    if task.retries > 0:
        return
    subject = f'Task [{task.name}] failed'
    message = f"""Task ID: {task.id}
Args: {task.args}
Kwargs: {task.kwargs}
Exception: {exc}
{traceback.format_exc()}"""
    mail_admins(subject, message)
```

Answer (score 1):

See: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/traceback.html

Since you have the task instance you should be able to check if `retries==0`.

A more standard way to do this is to attach an email handler at loglevel ERROR to the huey consumer logger. That's the way I would handle it.

Comment: Thanks @coleifer. I did attach the `mail_admins` to the "huey consumer logger" `huey.consumer`. However that basically "swallows" all other types of log levels; for example, no output is shown when running `manage.py run_huey` locally.

Answer (score 1):

On 1. I think you can check `task.retries`?

On 2. use [traceback.format_exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception) ?